# change javascript variable from codebehind on callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Ok, so I have been spinning my wheels on this one for a long time now, and as usual, i am sure that this is a really simple fix, so here goes...

I need to set a javascript variable using a variable from my code-behind file. Normally, I do it as follows:

```
var Test = <%= TestVar%>
```

On a normal page load, this method (while probably not the best way to do it) works great for me. The problem that I am now having, is that I need to change the variable on a callback with a callback/update panel. What I have, is the variable is set in a javascript block in the page header, and I then call a function that utilizes the variable on the callback panel's EndCallback event.

```
var Var1 = <%= Var1%>;
function endCallback()
{
    //some action with Var1;
}
```

Everything runs great, except that the server tag is not reloaded (because I am not doing a full page postback). Is there a better way to update a javascript variable on a partial postback?

Comment: In order to access the server once a page has been loaded, you must use `ajax`.

Comment: Exactly - use some kind of Ajax call, which responds with the new value for your variable.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what a generic ajax call to the server would look like?

Comment: @scholzr - Create a web service and just include `YourService.asmx/js` as a script file.  ASP.NET will generate all the script proxies for you, it's super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change a server variable, you need an ajax call.
Using jquery or another method.
On server-side you need to create a method, maybe a web service. And then invoke it from the client-side sending the new value.

client side:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "(webservice url)",
   data:(parameters if needed),
   success:function(response){
        variable = response;
   }
});
```

server-side:

```
[WebMethod()]
public object GetValue(object param1){
   ...
   return new_value;
}
```